# Is there a way to rescue my processor from a reset deadlock

Tags: microcontroller, infinite-loop, infineon

I have a board with an XMC1400 MCU on it. It is a custom board with LEDs and buttons and so on.
So I accidentally add a '''XMC_SCU_RESET_AssertMasterReset()''' line at the beginning of the code... This function cause xmc to reset but it doesn't just reset the program counter, it also clears everything and ends the debug connection. And since it happens so quickly I cannot reconnect before it resets again. For the one who doesn't know, when you load a program to the xmc, it gets written to the flash, and once it's loaded it will always run with power up.
I know in some boards there are some pins used to clear to board when shorted but there is no such a thing in this one.
There are however several bootstrap loaders(can and uart). But they are disabled by a flash parameter called BMI. I don't have much hope but is there a way to rescue this processor?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you programming it using something like a JTAG? If so then it should be possible to do something while it is under reset. If you are relying on a bootloader then you're  out of luck

Comment: I am using SWD. Its ARM's JTAG but not as functional as JTAG apparently because I am not able to connect to it through debugger.